# model passed to dictionary is of type .Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery , but it requires a model of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

What I am trying to do is

UserRoles:

```
public class UserRolesController : Controller
{
    private HMSEntities db = new HMSEntities();
    //
    // GET: /UserRoles/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User user = (User)Session["User"];
        var usr = db.Users.Find(user.Id);
        ViewBag.Id = usr.Id;
        ViewBag.FirstName = usr.FirstName;
        if (Session["User"] != null)
        {
            var role = db.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == user.RoleId);
        }
        return View(usr);

    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<HMS.Models.User>
@using HMS.Models;
```

In this project when a user logs in then the user can view their details and then perform crud operations on roles of that user, but I am getting an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[HMS.Models.Role]', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[HMS.Models.User]'.

My Models are:

Role.cs

```
public partial class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

User.cs

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Accesses = new HashSet<Access>();
        this.Doctors = new HashSet<Doctor>();
        this.Patients = new HashSet<Patient>();
        this.Staffs = new HashSet<Staff>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DOB { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Age { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhoneNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> LandlineNO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Status { get; set; }
    public string PermentAddress { get; set; }
    public string TemproryAddress { get; set; }
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string EducationFinal { get; set; }
    public string Experience { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Access> Accesses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Doctor> Doctors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Staff> Staffs { get; set; }
}
```

I am new to mvc and don't know what else to do. If any further code is required please do tell and please reply.

Comment: Your view specifies has `@model IEnumerable<HMS.Models.User>` but you controller has `return View(ViewBag.role);` (why are you putting it into `ViewBag` first anyway) which is a collection of `Role`, not `User`. Bit unclear what you really want to show in the view

Comment: I changed my code and I am putting the value in a var now. I want to display user details as well as perform operations on roles but since user has foreign key reference I am using @model IEnumerable<HMS.Models.User>

Comment: If your wanting to return one user and their roles, then the model would need to be `@model HMS.Models.User` and you would need to return `User` (populated with their roles). Difficult to give your the correct code without knowing your models.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have now added my models in this question. Please check it

Comment: typeof `User` contains property `Role` (not `IEnumerable<Role>`) so your current code does not make much sense. What are you actually trying to do in the view, for example do you want to display/edit one user, but be able to edit/select their role from a collection of all roles?

Comment: @StephenMuecke A user can log in then that user wil see his details and can perform crud operations on the roles

Comment: But a user has only **one** role according to your model (so _"perform crud operations on the roles"_ (plural) does not make sense) . Are you wanting to display a dropdownlist with all roles so that one can be selected?

Comment: the user should be able to create, edit, display or delete roles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84667/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-itaws).

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == user.RoleId);
```

Returns a DBQuery:

You have to convert it to List or Enumerable.

```
ViewBag.role = db.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == user.RoleId).AsEnumerable();

return View(ViewBag.role);
```

OR if you use List:

```
ViewBag.role = db.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == user.RoleId).ToList();
```

And you don't need to put in ViewBag:

```
var roles = db.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == user.RoleId).AsEnumerable();

 return View(roles);
```

And in your View Change the Model from User to Roles:

```
@model IEnumerable<HMS.Models.User>
```

To `Roles`

```
@model IEnumerable<HMS.Models.Roles>
```

**EDIT:**

You are returning a Enumerable of Roles on this LINE: `if (usr != null)  return View(ViewBag.role);` Not a User.

If you want to return the User and the Roles, you have to include the Roles in the User Model.

Something Like this in controller:

```
var usr = db.Users.Find(user.Id);
usr.Roles = db.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == user.RoleId).ToList();

return View(usr);
```

Then in the View:

```
@model HMS.Models.User

@foreach(var role in Model.Roles){

   <p>@role.RoleId</p>

}
```

Comment: That will still throw an exception because the model is `@model IEnumerable<HMS.Models.User>` not `@model IEnumerable<HMS.Models.Role>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I noticed that, and suggested to change Model in View

Comment: @Dawood Awan Why should the view change to roles when it has only id and name field whereas user has foreign key reference to roleid

Comment: @DawoodAwan When I tried to do your edited post I am getting an error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<HMS.Models.Role>' to 'HMS.Models.Role'

Comment: On Which Line? @Itaws

Comment: usr.Roles = db.Roles.Where(u => u.Id == user.RoleId).ToList();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84665/discussion-between-itaws-and-dawood-awan).